# Android context getPackageManager hasSystemFeature

Tags: java, android, package-managers

This is my code in java:

```
public class TestAudio extends Activity {
    private TextView t1;
    private Context context;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_audio);
        t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.t1);
        System.out.println("aaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
        PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();

        System.out.println("bbbbbbbbbbbbbb");
        if(packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_MICROPHONE)){
            t1.setText("I'm here");
        }else{
            t1.setText("gg");
        }

    }
```

Why does it stop response when it executes to the code between the two `system.out.print`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm presuming that the error your getting is NPE. Since your `context` has not been initialized yet. Initialize it first.

Comment: Thank you! Now I know what the problem is, I cannot just instantiate a Context object

Comment: Do properly tag your post as answered by accepting the answer that's helped you @MarvinC Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You have not initialized your context. To get the package manager you can use your activity's context. Get the activity's context to initialize package manager:

```
PackageManager packageManager = this.getPackageManager();
```

Or simply

```
PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I know what the problem is, I cannot just instantiate a Context object

Answer (score 0):

Init your context before use it:

```
this.context = getApplicationContext();
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I know what the problem is, I cannot just instantiate a Context object